# Use case of Result in Asynchronous programming

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a long Running asynchronous method called Compute() and I want to call it from a Parent Method. Below are the two approaches I have implemented.

Approach 1:

```
public string ParentMethod()
{   
    var computedResult = Compute().Result;
    return computedResult;
}
```

Approach 2:

```
public string ParentMethod()
{   
    var computedTask= Compute();
    var computedResult = computedTask.Result;
    return computedResult;
}
```

I know Approach2 is very bad as many articles suggests but have no idea about Approach1.
Is Both approaches are the same??If not is it good practice to use Approach1.

I know i can use async and await in parentMethod as below and I want to know particularly about above approaches.

```
public async Task<string> ParentMethod()
{   
    var computedTask= await Compute();
    return computedResult;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: They are the same. You just introduced an variable which possibly will be even optimized by compiler.

Comment: @GuruStron - Yes, the compiler would optimize both to be the same as Approach 1.

Comment: 1 & 2 are both technically wrong, and will not work in real world situations (but will appear to work right until you put the code into production whilst you are demoing to the boss!).  Using Task based techniques in non-task based code is never a good solution.  If you are unable to use Task based techniques properly (and you really should), then you could use `Compute().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but TBH you shouldn't (have I said that enough yet).

Answer (score 2):

The number of use-cases for `.Result` are *basically* zero. The *one* valid usage is in a niche scenario where you want to avoid an async state-machine (i.e. a non-`async` method) in a tight loop when there's a good chance that some *inner*-operation will often complete synchronously, by checking `.IsCompletedSuccessfully` on a task/value-task - and *only if this is true*, accessing `.Result` (exactly once). In all other cases: you should `await`, which usually means using a fallback to an `async` method.

Your options 1 and 2 are functionally identical.

Comment: I sort of understand all the articles that have been written about it is that if you're writing some kind of framework that deals with tasks, then .Result is one of the tools you can use, implied is of course that you know **exactly** what you're doing since you're writing such a library. In all other cases, it is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah, honestly: I wouldn't expect to see `.Result` or `.IsCompletedSuccessfully` accessed outside of very specific library code; most application code, and probably almost all library code: should just use `await`